# how can I integrate solr and nutch in Cloudera

Tags: solr, hdfs, cloudera, nutch, apache-zookeeper

I get Starting Zookeeper and solr service and in Cloudera Manager also I had create a HDFS.But i still not able to get working nutch and solr together in Cloudera.
I do not know the following steps in order to get crawling and indexing new urls and get Query Result of solr index.

Does anyone know how to proceed?

Comment: Do you mean how to get nutch crawled data stored at Solr?

Comment: I had started with Nutch and solr and I had got crawling urls and Indexing its but not in cloudera.now i want to integrate them in cloudera-hadoop.

Comment: You have to transfer your schema.xml to cloudera one. Do you want to try solr in distributed mode (SolrCloud) or single mode?

Comment: I want to strat with the easy mode.So can you tell me the following step in case we use Single Mode.